# "Cannot Find Module", when it is both in package.json and node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

When I include `require.resolve('openzeppelin-solidity')` in my code, I get an error:

`Cannot find module 'openzeppelin-solidity'`

However, when I look at my packages.json, I see `"openzeppelin-solidity": "^2.1.2"` in the dependencies.

I can also see a directory `node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/` with all the module files.

My hunch is this is because the `openzeppelin-solidity` package does not have a `main` file listed in package.json, but can't find anything to confirm or deny

Comment: You have right: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules I think you need a solidity project to use that module

Comment: What were you trying to accomplish? I'm one of the maintainers of OpenZeppelin. We don't have a `main` file because it's not a JavaScript project. Let me know if you think we need one.

Comment: @frangio I have a `oathforge` project that avoids truffle. We need to `fs.readFile` the OpenZeppelin contracts. It works fine until `oathforge` is included in a dependency, because the OpenZeppelin contracts could be in `node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity` or `node_modules/oathforge/node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity`. I found a workaround which I posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manuel Spigolon confirmed the lack of `main` is the issue in a comment on the question.

You can get around this with `path.dirname(require.resolve('openzeppelin-solidity/package.json'))`